# Force Application refresh on back button

Tags: caching, refresh, back-button

I have a web app which pulls in information via ajax after the page loads. When a user leaves the page, then hits the 'back' button in their browser, they see the page as it looked on initial load. What I need to have happen is have all javascript run as if they hit the 'refresh' button.

I have tried setting the Cache-Control and Pragma headers, but this didn't help. I know this is possible, as Google does it in many of their applications, such as gmail and google reader. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `window.onpopstate=function() { location.reload(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Really Simple History](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) - it's a JavaScript library that lets AJAX applications interact with the Back and Forward buttons using the same techniques that Gmail and family use.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick! I didn't think I needed a history manager since I didn't care about backing through multiple ajax events, it was only the last state that I cared about. Still, I got RSH implemented, and it's working smoothly now!