# partial ajax update with back button

Tags: javascript, ajax, back

I'm doing partial update to the page with Ajax which is a shopping cart that updates with Ajax as users add items to it. The problem is that if users move to checkout and then hit the back button the shopping cart looks empty as it was updated with Ajax. Refreshing the page make items appear again.

Is there a way to force updating the page on back button?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470249/force-application-refresh-on-back-button

Answer (score 0):

If you use the history.pushstate in your ajax app, you can keep the contents of the card in a variable in the global namespace (e.g. window.cartItems = { item1, item2, ... }), and after back button is pressed and the previous button is rendered again, get your items from that global object.

Comment: the problem is that the second page is not Ajax! so I'm moving from a page that had parts of it updated with Ajax to another page without going to it through Ajax!

Comment: If you still have Javascript code on the non-ajax page, it can be handled since global variables can be accessed from every jscript-enabled page.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against altering the behavior of the back button itself. Users expect the Back button to take them back a page, not to do anything else.

I would suggest a different approach. For example, you could have a piece of JS that runs on the cart page itself. This script would grab all the cart data from the backend. The script could run once when the page loads, ensuring that the cart is up-to-date.